# How to retrieve email alias and CN for everyone in an AD group using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-cmdlet

I am using PowerShell with the Quest AD cmdlets.

I can use the Get-QADGroupMember cmdlet to get a list of everyone in a given group. So far so good but I would like to get their email alias as well. All that is returned currently is something like:

```
Name      Type  DN
----      ----  --
Jane Doe  User  CN=Jane Doe,OU=Employee,DC=companyname,DC=com
Job Blow  User  CN=Joe Blow,OU=Employee,DC=companyname,DC=com
```

I tried using get-qaduser with the -includeallproperties flag but I still only get the above fields returned and I don't know how to get at the returned data which the documentation says is cached on the computer.

Any help would be appreciated.

***UPDATE***

I ended up using "select" similar to below:

```
$everyone = Get-QADGroupMember "All employees" | select firstname, lastname, email
```

And that got everything I needed into an array of hashtables. At that point it is easy to do whatever is needed by iterating through everyone with code like:

```
for ($i=0; $i -le $everyone .length-1; $i++)
{
    write-host $everyone[$i].email
}
```

Took me forever to find the "." notation for pulling specific values out of the hashtable. I did text parsing and that worked but I knew that couldn't be the right way of doing it and eventually found documentation on the dot notation. I hope documenting that here saves someone else some time!

Comment: @Joey
I was not aware of those options. I tried piping into Format-List -Force * and that gave me MORE than enough attributes. I just need to do some data massaging now and I'll have everything I need to get my task done. Thanks for posting!

Comment: I posted it as an answer now. I would have, if I had any experience using PowerShell for server administration but I don't have a clue of that, neither of the AD cmdlets/types, so I felt safer using a comment just in case that was a wrong idea :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure it really doesn't return that information? Have you tried piping the command into `Get-Member` or `Format-List -Force *`? PowerShell can be configured to only show a few properties of items and not all which might be the case here.

You can select properties using `Select-Object` or just `select` if you konw they are there, even though PowerShell doesn't display them by default:

```
Some-Command | select Name, Type, DN, SomeOtherProperty
```

You can see this for example with `Get-ChildItem` too:

```
PS Home:\> gci *.ps1


    Directory: C:\Users\Joey


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---        2011-04-27     18:50        169 format.ps1
-a---        2011-04-26     18:36       1064 Untitled1.ps1
-a---        2011-04-27     18:41         69 x.ps1
-a---        2011-04-23     19:58         91 y.ps1
```

The normal invocation only yields four properties: `Mode`, `LastWriteTime`, `Length` and `Name`. However, there are plenty more, as `Get-Member` shows.

```
PS Home:\> gci *.ps1|gm -MemberType Property


   TypeName: System.IO.FileInfo

Name              MemberType Definition
----              ---------- ----------
Attributes        Property   System.IO.FileAttributes Attributes {get;set;}
CreationTime      Property   System.DateTime CreationTime {get;set;}
CreationTimeUtc   Property   System.DateTime CreationTimeUtc {get;set;}
Directory         Property   System.IO.DirectoryInfo Directory {get;}
DirectoryName     Property   System.String DirectoryName {get;}
Exists            Property   System.Boolean Exists {get;}
Extension         Property   System.String Extension {get;}
FullName          Property   System.String FullName {get;}
IsReadOnly        Property   System.Boolean IsReadOnly {get;set;}
LastAccessTime    Property   System.DateTime LastAccessTime {get;set;}
LastAccessTimeUtc Property   System.DateTime LastAccessTimeUtc {get;set;}
LastWriteTime     Property   System.DateTime LastWriteTime {get;set;}
LastWriteTimeUtc  Property   System.DateTime LastWriteTimeUtc {get;set;}
Length            Property   System.Int64 Length {get;}
Name              Property   System.String Name {get;}
```

Comment: Using "select" is just what I'm looking for so I can pull just the fields I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rememember that select-object strips down the object and generates new ones.

So in this example:

```
$test = get-qaduser atestuser | select-object name
```

$test will be a PSCustomObject (System.Object) containing only the name.

What do you want do do with the data? Output to the console...to a file?

I would do something like this:

```
get-qadgroupmember "domain users" | format-table name, displayname, email
```

Or

```
get-qadgroupmember "domain users" | select-object name, displayname, email | Export-Csv c:\acsvfile.csv
```

Comment: I am going to take the output and use it to reconcile NT accounts in a database. Having a little difficulty getting it converted to an array though. I can convert everything to text and parse but I'm sure that is the brute force way of doing things.